# Создаем модальное окно

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript, html, css

Такой вопрос. Хочу сделать модальное окно своими руками. При помощи `JavaScript`, `jQuery`. НО! Без использования `jQuery UI`!!! Т.е. нужно создать скрытый `DIV`, показать его в нужный момент и убрать его с глаз долой :-)) (по нажатию кнопки). Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function createBlock(){
    var block = document.createElement('div');
    block.className = 'overlay'
    block.innerHTML = 'любая html верстка окна с текстом и кнопками'
    document.body.appendChild(block);
}
```

а дальше в цсс описываете стили для .overlay и его содержимого

```
width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;left:0;
    z-index:999;
```

Comment: А как теперь скрыть его?

Comment: >'любая html верстка окна с текстом и кнопками'

там будет содержаться кнопка, обработчик клика которой будет делать, что-то вроди ``$('.overlay').hide();``

Comment: А сам `DIV` убрать таким же способом можно(а не скрыть), ато разведется у меня на сайте кучка скрытых дивов)

Comment: [.remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)